# here is the code to fetch username and password from the xml file but it does't fetch the the data?

Tags: flex4, flex3, flash-cs5, flash

Here is the code to fetch username and password from the xml file but it does't fetch the the data?

```
private var myXML: XML = new XML();
private function connect(event: Event): void {
  var str1: String = username.text.toString();
  trace(str1);
  var str2: String = password.text.toString();
  trace(str2);
  var str3: String = myXML.authentication.username;
  Alert.show(str3);
  var str4: String = myXML.authentication.password;
  if (str1 == str3 && str2 == str4) {
    Alert.show("sucessfully Connected")
  } else {
    Alert.show("invalid username password");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where you are assigning data for myXML and what is your xml?

```
var settingFile:File;
var stream:FileStream;
var resultXML:XML;
settingFile = settingFile.resolvePath("setting.xml");
        stream = new FileStream;
        if(settingFile.exists)
        {
            stream.open(settingFile,FileMode.READ);
          resultXML = XML(stream.readUTFBytes(stream.bytesAvailable));
         stream.close();
         var xmlDoc:XMLDocument = new XMLDocument(resultXML.toString());
         var decoder:SimpleXMLDecoder = new SimpleXMLDecoder(true);
         var resultObj:Object = decoder.decodeXML(xmlDoc);
}
```

from that resultObj u can access the username and password

if you are using FlexApplication then convert the xml file to xmlDocument and decode it. then from the decoded object you can get the username and password.

```
     var xmlDoc:XMLDocument = new XMLDocument(myXML.toString());
     var decoder:SimpleXMLDecoder = new SimpleXMLDecoder(true);
     var resultObj:Object = decoder.decodeXML(xmlDoc);
```

you can try like this.

```
private var myXML: XML = new XML();


private function connect(event: Event): void {

var xmlDoc:XMLDocument = new XMLDocument(myXML.toString());
var decoder:SimpleXMLDecoder = new SimpleXMLDecoder(true);
var resultObj:Object = decoder.decodeXML(xmlDoc);

var str1: String = username.text.toString();
trace(str1);
var str2: String = password.text.toString();
trace(str2);
var str3: String = resultObj.authentication.username;
Alert.show(str3);
var str4: String = resultObj.authentication.password;
if (str1 == str3 && str2 == str4) {
  Alert.show("sucessfully Connected")
} else {
  Alert.show("invalid username password");
}
}
```

Comment: myxml is the object and xml is my setting file from there i have to fetch the username and password...

Comment: I have modified my answer. Try like this. This will work in Desktop Application.

Comment: i don't want to convert xmlfile to xmldocument and then decode
i just want to fetch the username and password from the xml file in the simple way????

Comment: I think we cannot read the xml file directly. we should convert the file into object then we can access that.

Comment: ya i want in the same way..??

Comment: i have given the exact code on that day itself.. is it working fine..?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to load the XML file suing the URL loader and capture the COMPLETE event to fetch the data?